# Passing a new keys into AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I installed aws cli and supplied the aws access key ID and secret access key. Everything worked perfectly!. I then deleted the user as I have no need for it anymore. I have then created a new user (which has different access key ID and secret access key).
The issue:
When I type

```
aws configure
```

I get:

```
AWS Access Key ID [****…]
AWS Secret Access Key [****...]
```

So the command prompt is using the previous keys.

How do I enter the new keys into the command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ignore the old key and input your new key, It will be overwrited.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add one more way to do it. This is particularly useful, if you do not want to override your current user but add another one instead.

You can use the profile option to add more credentials:
`aws configure --profile <my-new-profile-name>` [1]

If you do not use the profile option, you are implicitly configuring the *default*'s profile credentials.

If you want to use a profile afterwards, each aws cli command provides the profile option, e.g.: `aws s3 ls --profile <my-new-profile-name>` [2]

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html